# How to use Pytorch Tokenize without punctuation and all lowercase?

Tags: pytorch, nltk, spacy

source_string = "first a modest refactor to fit the current project size and second a full refactor
to move all our code into plugins dont feel like you have to code along to this whole book"

target_string = "first, a modest refactor to fit the current project size, and second, a full refactor
to move all our code into plugins. don't feel like you have to code along to this whole book."

Which pytorch model should we use?

I learned that neither spacy nor nltk could recognize the sentence correctly.

Gradually, I guess there are no python libraries directly available,

so hopefully someone can give me more advice. and any example?

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: if you find the answer useful, please consider upvoting it. Also, please consider accepting it (with the tick mark ✓ next to it) if you deem it correct or, alternatively, please describe in a comment why you consider it incorrect or not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a previous step to add punctuation and proper casing to the text. For this, you may use [Re-punctuate](https://huggingface.co/SJ-Ray/Re-Punctuate).

```
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, TFT5ForConditionalGeneration

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('SJ-Ray/Re-Punctuate')
model = TFT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('SJ-Ray/Re-Punctuate')

input_text = 'first a modest refactor to fit the current project size and second a full refactor to move all our code into plugins dont feel like you have to code along to this whole book'
inputs = tokenizer.encode("punctuate: " + input_text, return_tensors="tf") 
result = model.generate(inputs)

decoded_output = tokenizer.decode(result[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
print(decoded_output)
```